# xcode 6 swift ads GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ads, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6 + Swift.

Does anybody know how to **integrate Google Ads**, **GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS** on a **Swift** Project?
how to config, and how to program?

I created a new file `Teste-Bridging-Header.h` on the project and put `#import GADBannerView.h`
based on [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_74)

on my `ViewController.swift` some thing like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {   
     override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)    

        var adB = GADBannerView()
        adB.delegate = self
        adB.rootViewController = self
        adB.adUnitID =  MY_ADS_ID //"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX"       
     }
}
```

**Am I going in the right direction? Can I get some examples?**

```
now its working...

on .h created  Objective-C bridging header I put: 
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"

my swift file:

    class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

         override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            var adB = GADBannerView( frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50) )
            adB.delegate = self
            adB.rootViewController = self
            adB.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX"

            var reqAdB = GADRequest()
            //reqAdB.testDevices = [ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ] //not working, dont know why
            //reqAdB.testDevices = ["Simulator"] //not working, dont know why

            adB.loadRequest(reqAdB)        
            self.view.addSubview(adB)

         }

    }
```

Comment: Is it working? If yes, then you are *going in the right direction*.

Comment: console says:2014-07-15 10:21:33.464 Teste[1239:39911] <Google> Category methods are not loaded. Make sure you link the Google Mobile Ads library using one of the -ObjC, -force_load, or -all_load linker flags. See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios for more information.
2014-07-15 10:21:36.520 Teste[1239:39911] +[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xa49aa4
2014-07-15 10:21:36.543 Teste[1239:39911] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: unrecognized selecto

Comment: If that's an error, then please edit your post and add the error, explaining it and formatting it properly. You need to provide good detail on your question to get help.

Comment: Yeah, it was an error, i fix it by Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Liniker Flags: Debug = -ObjC ; Release : -ObjC ... maybe im going to the right direction... :)

Comment: BTW: You're calling the wrong super class method (*viewWillAppear* vs. *viewDidAppear*).

Comment: @Codo viewDidAppear is working... tks

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get everything compiling and working by using this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
        self.view.frame.size.height -
            CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height); // place at bottom of view

    var size = GADAdSizeFullWidthPortraitWithHeight(50) // set size to 50
    var adB = GADBannerView(adSize: size, origin: origin) // create the banner
    adB.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID  //"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX"
    adB.delegate = self // ??
    adB.rootViewController = self // ??
    self.view.addSubview(adB) // ??
    var request = GADRequest() // create request
    request.testDevices = [ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ]; // set it to "test" request
    adB.loadRequest(request) // actually load it (?)
}
```

To get it to work, I had to make sure to include "*_*-Bridging-Header.h" (with your project name) in the "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section, "Objective-C Bridging Header" field (as original posted suggested).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need  to do all the Objective-C bridging stuff. I also had this problem and had to search the framework files for clues. I found a comment that included the updated definition name: kDFPSimulatorID

So just change it to this:

```
request.testDevices = [kDFPSimulatorID]
```

Should work.