# AdMob banner using swift in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob

I've successfully used **admob** in previous apps using **objective c** but I seem to be having problems getting this to work in **swift**.

Using the following code in `viewDidAppear` will successfully show a test ad.

```
var adB = GADBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)) // create the banner
    adB.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx"
    adB.delegate = self
    adB.rootViewController = self

    var request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [GAD_SIMULATOR_ID];

    adB.loadRequest(request)
    self.view.addSubview(adB)
```

Some help for this came from the following question:
[xcode 6 swift ads GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760156/xcode-6-swift-ads-googlemobileadssdkios)

However my issue is when I want to remove the test ads in preparation for the app store. In my previous apps the only difference I can see is that I removed the lines for "request" and have the following line instead:

```
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Trying this in swift:

```
adB.loadRequest(GADRequest().request)
```

brings up the following error:

```
"GADRequest does not have a member named 'request'"
```

Leaving 'request' out does not bring up any ads. Has anyone had any success with admob using swift to bring up live ads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is how I successfully load live ads with swift:

```
    bannerDisplayed = false

    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    bannerView?.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-blub"
    bannerView?.delegate = self
    bannerView?.rootViewController = self
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView!)
    var request:GADRequest = GADRequest()

    if testRun {
        var devices: [String] = ["abc", "xyze"]
        request.testDevices = devices
    }

    bannerView?.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hi, would this bring up live ads in the simulator? The code looks similar to mine except for the bannerDisplayed line and the question marks being used. I still can't get any live ads to appear in the simulator.

Comment: I used this https://github.com/goldenfiredo/Swift_GoogleAd and I get live ads in the simulator! Whats your error message?

Comment: I don't get an error message just no ad banner. I'll have a look at the link later. Thanks.

Comment: @user1759949 : What did you do, I am on swift and having the same error no ad showing up

Comment: request.testDevices = [kGADAdSizeBanner] could be used to test